# entity framework relationship issue

Tags: entity-framework, relationship

I have the foloowing models:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { set; get; }

        public virtual Location Location { set; get; }

    }
    public class Location {

        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string NAME { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> LocationEmployees { get; set; }

    }
```

Basically an employee belongs to a location and a location has a lot of employees. I want to add a column to the location model called location contact which will be an employee id. I have tried adding it through code first migrations but it is not yielding the expected results.

Added columns

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { set; get; }

        public virtual Location Location { set; get; }

    }
    public class Location {

        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string NAME { set; get; }

        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> LocationEmployees { get; set; }

    }
```

Migration file generated:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "LocationID", "dbo.Locations");
            DropIndex("dbo.Employees", new[] { "LocationID" });
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Employees", name: "LocationID", newName: "Location_ID");
            AddColumn("dbo.Locations", "EmployeeID", c => c.Int(nullable: true));
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "Location_ID", "dbo.Locations", "ID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "LocationID", "dbo.Locations", "ID", cascadeDelete: false);
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Locations", "EmployeeID", "dbo.Employees", "ID", cascadeDelete: false);
            CreateIndex("dbo.Employees", "Location_ID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Employees", "LocationID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Locations", "EmployeeID");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("dbo.Locations", new[] { "EmployeeID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Employees", new[] { "LocationID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Employees", new[] { "Location_ID" });
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Locations", "EmployeeID", "dbo.Employees");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "LocationID", "dbo.Locations");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "Location_ID", "dbo.Locations");
            DropColumn("dbo.Locations", "EmployeeID");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Employees", name: "Location_ID", newName: "LocationID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Employees", "LocationID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Employees", "LocationID", "dbo.Locations", "ID", cascadeDelete: false);
        }
```

I am getting this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Foreign key 'FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Locations_LocationID' references invalid column 'LocationID' in referencing table 'Employees'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Foreign key 'FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Locations_LocationID' references invalid column 'LocationID' in referencing table 'Employees'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why the migration throws this exception but it is obvious that it doesn't create the relations you want to have. You can see it in the `Up` method when *three* foreign keys are added instead of *two*. EF creates three relationships here, one of them has the default FK name `Location_ID`.

The reason is that EF doesn't know if `Employee.Location` has `Location.Employee` or `Location.LocationEmployees` as the inverse navigation property.

You must define this explicitly with either data annotations...

```
public class Employee
{
    //...

    [InverseProperty("LocationEmployees")]
    public virtual Location Location { set; get; }
}
```

...or with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasMany(l => l.LocationEmployees)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Location)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.LocationID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasOptional(l => l.Employee)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(l => l.EmployeeID);
```

Note that I have used `HasOptional` instead of `HasRequired` in the second relationship which means that you also must make the FK in your `Location` model nullable:

```
public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

Both relationships can't be required since there is no valid ordering `Employee` and `Location` entities could be inserted into the database because they would be mutually dependent on each other.

Alternatively you can also make the other relationship with `int? LocationID` in `Employee` optional if that fits better to your business requirements.

Comment: Thanks alot. I hope one day to attain your understanding of EF.